# Visual C# storing and reading custom options to and from a custom XML in Appdata

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xml-parsing, settings

I have an app that I am converting from VB to C# in Visual Studio 2013 and .NET does not anymore support `PrivateProfileString` but wants me to use XML instead.

I need help of a very simple code that can store and read two strings `setting1` and `setting2` in an XML and read it back from it.

I would like to know what is the most effective way of going about this. Is it with using `XMLDocument` or and `XMLWriter`?

If somebody could give me a simple script, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a `settings.xml` file somewhere that contains:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Settings>
    <Section1>
        <Key1>Value1</Key1>
        <Key2>Value2</Key2>
    </Section1>
    <Section2>
        <Key1>Value3</Key1>
        <Key2>Value4</Key2>
        <KeyX>Value5</KeyX>
    </Section2>
</Settings>
```

Then you can have a `SettingsProvider` class like this:

```cs
using System.Xml.Linq;

public static class SettingsProvider
{
    private const string settingsFileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "settings.xml");

    private static XDocument settings;

    static SettingsProvider()
    {
        try
        {
            settings = XDocument.Load(settingsFileName);
        }
        catch
        {
            settings = XDocument.Parse("<Settings/>");
        }
    }

    public static string GetValue(string section, string key, string defaultValue)
    {
        XElement settingElement = GetSettingElement(section, key);

        return settingElement == null ? defaultValue : settingElement.Value;
    }

    public static void SetValue(string section, string key, string value)
    {
        XElement settingElement = GetSettingElement(section, key, true);

        settingElement.Value = value;
        settings.Save(settingsFileName);
    }

    private static XElement GetSettingElement(string section, string key, bool createIfNotExist = false)
    {
        XElement sectionElement =
            settings
                .Root
                .Elements(section)
                .FirstOrDefault();

        if (sectionElement == null)
        {
            if (createIfNotExist)
            {
                sectionElement = new XElement(section);
                settings.Root.Add(sectionElement);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        XElement settingElement =
            sectionElement
                .Elements(key)
                .FirstOrDefault();

        if (settingElement == null)
        {
            if (createIfNotExist)
            {
                settingElement = new XElement(key);
                sectionElement.Add(settingElement);
            }
        }

        return settingElement;
    }

    public static void RemoveSetting(string section, string key)
    {
        XElement settingElement = GetSettingElement(section, key);

        if (settingElement == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        XElement sectionElement = settingElement.Parent;

        settingElement.Remove();

        if (sectionElement.IsEmpty)
        {
            sectionElement.Remove();
        }

        settings.Save(settingsFileName);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
string section1Key1 = SettingsProvider.GetValue("Section1", "Key1", "default");
SettingsProvider.SetValue("Section1", "Key1", "OtherValue");
SettingsProvider.SetValue("Section1", "Key2", "Value2");
SettingsProvider.SetValue("Section2", "Key1", "Value3");
SettingsProvider.RemoveSetting("Section2", "Key1");
SettingsProvider.RemoveSetting("Section1", "Key2");
```

Comment: This was excellent. I only modified the path to make it valid and also had to add an initialization method to create the empty root element if the file does not exist. See my edit proposal. Köszönöm szépen ;-)

Comment: Accepted your edit proposal. But replaced Initialize() method to static ctor to ensure that initialization is executed before use of `SettingsProvider`. Igazán nincs mit, én köszönöm. :)

Comment: OK, it was anyway executed first, because the `GetSettingElement` is always called first, which had the `Initialize()` method call first. But this is cleaner. I only did one more edit, to remove the call that is not needed anymore (and is not valid, since you changed the method to a constructor). Ha tetszik a kérdés, azt is felpontozhatod ;-) Köszi még egyszer, sokat segített.

Comment: @ib11 Edit suggestion approved. Anno én is belefutottam ebbe a mikor VB6-ról váltottam. :) Akkor még ez az oldal sem létezett. :)